# sql query to update product quantity with order quantity when status changes

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need an update query to loop through all b.quantityOrdered and subtract that amount from d.quantityInStock. The SQL loop shows precisely what I need to be updated:

```sql
select
d.productCode as prod,
b.quantityOrdered as qtyO,
d.quantityInStock as qtyIS

from orders a
left join orderdetails b on a.orderNumber=b.orderNumber
left join products d on b.productCode=d.productCode
where a.status=6 and a.invoiceStatus=4
order by 1 asc
```

Its result is:

```
 prod qtyO qtyIS
 104  19   110
 104  4    110
 104  20   110
 105  10   20
 105  15   20
 105  24   20
```

Even better, if I can make a function in MySql DB so when a.status changes from 5 to 6, this update function will loop the orderdetails table and subtract quantityordered on quantityinstock.

Or maybe a php function which does this?

Comment: Are you looking for [triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html)?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a MySQL trigger called `updateInStock` that does what you want.

```
CREATE TRIGGER updateInStock BEFORE UPDATE ON orders
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

UPDATE orders, orderdetails b, products d
SET d.quantityInStock = d.quantityInStock - b.quantityOrdered 
WHERE NEW.orderNumber = b.orderNumber AND b.productCode = d.productCode
AND OLD.status = 5 AND NEW.status = 6 AND 
OLD.invoiceStatus = 4 AND NEW.invoiceStatus = 4;

END;
```

The `UPDATE` command subtracts the quantity ordered from the quantity in stock for products whose status changed from 5 to 6 in the `orders` table and for which there was no change in `invoiceStatus`.  `OLD` and `NEW` are aliases for the `orders` table, the one associated with the trigger.  That's why I didn't use `a` as an alias for `orders`, the way you did in your `SELECT` statement.  Also, MySQL doesn't allow `ORDER BY` in multiple-table `UPDATE` commands.  Please check if updating the products in random order will cause problems for your application.

Note that I incorporated your `SELECT` statement's join conditions as part of the `UPDATE` statement's `WHERE` clause.  You were using a `LEFT JOIN`, but I think you meant to use an `INNER JOIN`.  Outer joins such as `LEFT JOIN` return all rows, even if there's no match in the other table.  In your case, you want only the rows where the order numbers and product codes match, so you need an `INNER JOIN`.

For more information on the `UPDATE` command in MySQL 5.6, refer to its documentation at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html.  Trigger documentation is at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-trigger.html.

Comment: mysql (tables are innoDB)  returns me a Error : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 8

Comment: btw. thanks a lot for your help, time and effort, much appreciated

Comment: Solved the error by adding delimiter, like this

     delimiter |
     
     CREATE TRIGGER updateInStock BEFORE UPDATE ON orders
     FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
     
     UPDATE orders, orderdetails b, products d
     SET d.quantityInStock = d.quantityInStock - b.quantityOrdered
     WHERE NEW.orderNumber = b.orderNumber AND b.productCode =     d.productCode
     AND OLD.status = 5 AND NEW.status = 6 AND 
     OLD.orders.invoiceStatus = 4 AND NEW.orders.invoiceStatus = 4;
     
     END;
     
     delimiter ;